# Getting data from firebase web

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch the data for a website using javascript. The problem I am getting is that I am unable to get the key of Users-->Rider-->rating-->key-->("**Rating Value**"). I am unable to find a syntax of it.

I want to retrieve the value of rating within this jQuery.

[image]

>

```
 <script>

database = firebase.database();

var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("Users").child("Riders");

ref.on('value',gotDataa,errDataa);

function gotDataa(data){
    //console.log(data.val());
    var Riders = data.val();
    var keys=Object.keys(Riders);
    console.log(keys);
    for(var i=0 ; i<keys.length;i++)
    {
        var k=keys[i];
        var car = Riders[k].car;
        var cnic = Riders[k].cnic;
        var email = Riders[k].email;
        var name = Riders[k].name;
        var phone = Riders[k].phone;
        var service = Riders[k].service;
        var rating = data.child("rating").child(keys).val();


$("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + phone +"</td><td>"+ email+"</td><td>"+ cnic +"</td><td>"+car+"</td><td>"+service+"</td><td>"+rating+"</td></tr>");

    }
}

function errDataa(err){

    console.log('Error');
    console.log(err);

}
</script>
```

I am getting `null` value of rating please correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(keys)`?

Comment: What about `console.log(data.val())`? Are you sure of the path?

Comment: keys are shown on console

Comment: all the values are working except rating I am getting all other values

Comment: Try `Riders[k].rating`.

Answer (score 0):

Do as follow:

```
var objRating = Riders[k].rating;

console.log(objRating[Object.keys(objRating)[0]]);
```

---

However, note that if you have only one rating per user you don't need to save the rating the way you save it (with an autogenerated node id): you can assign the rating directly to the rating node.

It means doing that:

```
-Riders
   - AIKI689EKJKJKJ....  //Rider ID
      - email: ....
      - name: ....
      .....
       - rating: 5
```

instead of:

```
 -Riders
   - AIKI689EKJKJKJ....  //Rider ID
      - email: ....
      - name: ....
      .....
       - rating
           - 57656YTYRRTGGH: 5
```

Comment: @K132133SyedArsalanHussain Did you have the opportunity to try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
function gotDataa(data){
 var Riders = data.val();
 data.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
 var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
 var childData = childSnapshot.val();
}
}
```